# SQL select unique column with maximum for 2nd column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Please how to combine maximum and distinct to have always unique Id and maximum of the column for that unique Id?

For example, if I have,

```
OrdinaceId Priloha2Id
5            1
5            2
6            2
6            4
7            1
```

result will be

```
OrdinaceId Priloha2Id
5             2
6             4
7             1
```

how to return only 1 row(with the same Id) with a maximum of Priloha2Id?

```
select * from (select 
distinct ord.Id as OrdinaceId,
ord.CleneniPzsId,
  posk.Id,
  posk.ICO as Ico,
  zar.ICZ as Icz,
  posk.NazevZkraceny as Zkratka,
  case when cle.Primariat = 0 then cle.Icp end as Icp,
  IIF(cle.Primariat = 1, pri.OborKod , cle.OdbornostKod) as OdbornostKod,
  ord.Nazev as OrdinaceNazev,
  (select Street + N' ' + DescriptiveNo + N', ' + PostCode +  N' ' + City from ICIS_Repl.repl.Address where Code = ord.NavAddressCode and Type = N'ORDINACE' and (ValidFrom is null or ValidFrom <= GETDATE()) and (ValidTill is null or ValidTill >= GETDATE() or ValidTill = N'1753-01-01 00:00:00')) as OrdinaceAdresaCela,
  pril.Id as Priloha2Id,
  cle.Smluvni,
  cisP2KomunikaceStav.Nazev as EP2,
  cisPzs.Nazev as StavPzp,
  pril.Status,
  pril.Info,
  pril.PriPlatnostOd as PlatnostOd,
  pril.PriPlatnostDo as PlatnostDo
from Ordinace ord
  left join CleneniPzs cle on cle.Id = ord.CleneniPzsId
  left join ZarizeniPZS zar on cle.ZarizeniPzsId = zar.Id
  left join PoskytovatelZS posk on zar.PoskytovatelZsId = posk.Id
  left join Primariat pri on cle.PrimariatId = pri.Id
  left join Pril2Formular pr on pr.CleneniPzsId = cle.Id
  left join Priloha2 pril on pril.Id = pr.Priloha2Id and (pril.PriPlatnostOd <= GETDATE() or pril.PriPlatnostOd is null) and (pril.PriPlatnostDo is null or pril.PriPlatnostDo >= GETDATE()) 
  join CisCiselnik cisP2KomunikaceStav on posk.P2KomunikaceStavKod = cisP2KomunikaceStav.Kod AND cisP2KomunikaceStav.Oblast = N'P2KomunikaceStav' and cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostDo is null or cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE()) 
  left join P2Formular form on form.Icp = cle.Icp and form.Aktivni = 1
  left join CisCiselnik cisPzs on form.P2StavPzpKod = cisPzs.Kod AND cisPzs.Oblast = N'P2StavPZP' and cisPzs.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (cisPzs.PlatnostDo is null or cisPzs.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE())  
  left join P2ZarizeniPZS z on form.P2ZarizeniPzsId = z.Id and z.Icz = zar.ICZ and z.PoskytovatelZsId = posk.Id
  join Smlouva smlv on smlv.Id = pril.SmlouvaId
  left join SmluvniVykon smlVyk on smlVyk.CleneniPzsId = cle.Id and smlVyk.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (smlVyk.PlatnostDo is null or smlVyk.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE())
  left join SmlVykonVyjadreniRL vyjadreni on vyjadreni.Id = smlVyk.VyjadreniRLId ) a
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I am using T-SQL

Comment: Your sample data does not appear to have any direct connection to the massive query below it.  Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: in my example are only 2 important columns OrdinaceId, Priloha2Id. I need to select all columns from select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression) to get max(Priloha2Id) per id. Then join to it.

Something like:

```
;with Pril2Formular_max_per_id as (
    select ord.Id as OrdinaceId, max(pr.Priloha2Id) as max_Priloha2Id
    from Ordinace ord
      left join CleneniPzs cle on cle.Id = ord.CleneniPzsId
      left join Pril2Formular pr on pr.CleneniPzsId = cle.Id
    group by ord.Id
)
select * from (select 
distinct ord.Id as OrdinaceId,[![enter image description here][1]][1]
ord.CleneniPzsId,
  posk.Id,
  posk.ICO as Ico,
  zar.ICZ as Icz,
  posk.NazevZkraceny as Zkratka,
  case when cle.Primariat = 0 then cle.Icp end as Icp,
  IIF(cle.Primariat = 1, pri.OborKod , cle.OdbornostKod) as OdbornostKod,
  ord.Nazev as OrdinaceNazev,
  (select Street + N' ' + DescriptiveNo + N', ' + PostCode +  N' ' + City from ICIS_Repl.repl.Address where Code = ord.NavAddressCode and Type = N'ORDINACE' and (ValidFrom is null or ValidFrom <= GETDATE()) and (ValidTill is null or ValidTill >= GETDATE() or ValidTill = N'1753-01-01 00:00:00')) as OrdinaceAdresaCela,
  pril.Id as Priloha2Id,
  cle.Smluvni,
  cisP2KomunikaceStav.Nazev as EP2,
  cisPzs.Nazev as StavPzp,
  pril.Status,
  pril.Info,
  pril.PriPlatnostOd as PlatnostOd,
  pril.PriPlatnostDo as PlatnostDo
from Ordinace ord
  left join CleneniPzs cle on cle.Id = ord.CleneniPzsId
  left join ZarizeniPZS zar on cle.ZarizeniPzsId = zar.Id
  left join PoskytovatelZS posk on zar.PoskytovatelZsId = posk.Id
  left join Primariat pri on cle.PrimariatId = pri.Id
  left join Pril2Formular_max_per_id pr on pr.OrdinaceId = ord.Id
  left join Priloha2 pril on pril.Id = pr.max_Priloha2Id and (pril.PriPlatnostOd <= GETDATE() or pril.PriPlatnostOd is null) and (pril.PriPlatnostDo is null or pril.PriPlatnostDo >= GETDATE()) 
  join CisCiselnik cisP2KomunikaceStav on posk.P2KomunikaceStavKod = cisP2KomunikaceStav.Kod AND cisP2KomunikaceStav.Oblast = N'P2KomunikaceStav' and cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostDo is null or cisP2KomunikaceStav.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE()) 
  left join P2Formular form on form.Icp = cle.Icp and form.Aktivni = 1
  left join CisCiselnik cisPzs on form.P2StavPzpKod = cisPzs.Kod AND cisPzs.Oblast = N'P2StavPZP' and cisPzs.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (cisPzs.PlatnostDo is null or cisPzs.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE())  
  left join P2ZarizeniPZS z on form.P2ZarizeniPzsId = z.Id and z.Icz = zar.ICZ and z.PoskytovatelZsId = posk.Id
  join Smlouva smlv on smlv.Id = pril.SmlouvaId
  left join SmluvniVykon smlVyk on smlVyk.CleneniPzsId = cle.Id and smlVyk.PlatnostOd <= GETDATE() and (smlVyk.PlatnostDo is null or smlVyk.PlatnostDo >= GETDATE())
  left join SmlVykonVyjadreniRL vyjadreni on vyjadreni.Id = smlVyk.VyjadreniRLId ) a ;
```

Comment: I am able to run query. but dont see any rows

Comment: @Bobek, I've fixed my query, was joining to wrong table at first

Comment: Glad it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

select Id, max(Priloha2Id) from table group by Id

Comment: I have modified your answer for my needs     select OrdinaceId, CleneniPzsId, Id, Ico, Icz, Zkratka, Icp, OdbornostKod, OrdinaceNazev, OrdinaceAdresaCela, Max(Priloha2Id) , Smluvni, EP2, StavPzp, Status, Info, PlatnostOd, PlatnostDo from (select........) a group by OrdinaceId    and getting following error Column 'a.CleneniPzsId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.